# Props change affecting previous components visited

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

In Registration process i have 3 screens
 1.Enter mobile Number
 2.Enter Otp
 3.Enter user data
   Here the problem is,When i hit finish button at final stage ,it dispatches the action and props will update,It also update the second component and getting error message [image]

**Enter Otp(2nd componet)**

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log(nextProps.commonState.res.data.kada)
   }
```

**Finish(3 rd component)**

```
this.props.register(Data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Console you nextProps and check if you are getting null in data?

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log(nextProps)
   }
```